# Website upload form connecting to cloud storage

Tags: html, forms, google-drive-api, dropbox, onedrive

I'm looking to create an upload form on my website and was interested in something similar to the "resume" upload form on Monster.com. I'm wondering if someone can point me to where I can find some information on how to connect to cloud storage. I can create the button to browse the local computer to select a file to upload but I'm not sure where to start when wanting to browse cloud storage.

[upload form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gshy2.png)

Comment: To clarify, you want to allow users to select their existing file from one of these cloud storage solution and pull it into your application?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.